# Extract lat/lon from overlapping raster files and assign value?

Tags: python, raster

I have two raster files that overlap (see picture below): one is a raster of a region (smaller picture on left top side), the other is the smoke plume in that region (huge black polygon blob). I am able to mask the areas that overlap, but how do I get the lat/lon coordinates and assign TRUE to areas that overlap? Both rasters have the same crs (EPSG:4326).

Sample files are accessible here in this link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2wwgr9mp3v8hrqq/AADCA24O8PC2qQ9fW_m0KYeda?dl=0

[image]

Here's what I have done to visualize that I can mask the overlapping areas from two rasters using Python:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.mask import mask
from shapely.geometry import box
import geopandas as gpd
from fiona.crs import from_epsg

# specify input/ouput filepaths
fp = r"\smoke_raster.tif"
out_tif = r"\masked_smoke_raster.tif"

data = rasterio.open(fp)
```

from the above code I can visualize the smoke extent:

[image]

```
#to mask areas where smoke covers region, I create a bounding box with Shapely (this is the bounding box of the region)
minx, miny = -139.1346, 47.65661
maxx, maxy = -110.4208, 60.03192
bbox = box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)

#Insert the bbox into a GeoDataFrame
geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': bbox}, index=[0], crs=from_epsg(4326))

#get the coordinates of the geometry compatible with rasterio
def getFeatures(gdf):
    """Function to parse features from GeoDataFrame compatible with rasterio"""
    import json
    return [json.loads(gdf.to_json())['features'][0]['geometry']]

coords = getFeatures(geo)
print(coords)

#clip raster with polygon
out_img, out_transform = mask(data, shapes=coords, crop=True)

with rasterio.open(out_tif, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_img)

clipped = rasterio.open(out_tif)
```

I can see that the raster is clipped and I see the regions covered by smoke appears white in this visualization:

[image]

How do I get the lat/lon coordinates and assign TRUE to areas that overlap?